# Leaflet Slider & Marker Cluster plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, leaflet, geojson

I hope you can help, I am new to this!

I am currently using the Leaflet Slider plugin to populate some geoJson data. This works absolutely fine however when the dataset becomes large the performance suffers considerably. I really want to use this plugin with Leaflet Marker cluster to improve performance and UI. Going off the instructions on GitHubthis is what I am doing so far:

```
 var capacity = capacityData //geojson ref

    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
    var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(capacity);

        markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);


    var layerGroup = L.layerGroup([markers]);


    //Create a marker layer (in the example done via a GeoJSON FeatureCollection)
    var testlayer = geoJsonLayer;
    var sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({ position: "topright", layer: layerGroup, range: true});

        //Make sure to add the slider to the map 
        map.addControl(sliderControl);

        //And initialize the slider
        sliderControl.startSlider();
```

This manages to get the data populated on the map in marker cluster format however the slider does not work? Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

[Link to Leaflet Slider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider)

[Link to Marker cluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)

Comment: Your GeoJSON layer contains time values inside the properties? can you paste part of it in?

Comment: Yeah it does. I have a time property and the plugin works if I just use the geojson layer.

Comment: var capacityData = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"time":"2016-03-24 15:55:58"},"geometry": {"type": "Point","coordinates":[lng here ,lat here]}},

Comment: Did this ever get solved?